# Spring JDBC - Stored Procedure returning an empty array

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc, sys-refcursor

I've done plenty of research on figuring out a way to return a result set using the Spring JDBC framework. I am new to Spring and I'm working on an implementation that calls a stored function that uses multiple input parameters and returns a ref cursor, but I can't seem to figure out the proper way of doing this. The code that I have now keeps returning an empty array. Can someone suggest to me what would be the best way of handling this?

Here's some of my code snippets:

```
 public class StandardRodsDAOImplementation implements StandardRodsDAO {

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private final String schema_name = "xxlt";
private final String procedure_catalog = "xxlt_bpg_std_width_pkg";
private final String procedure_name    = "get_std_rods";

public List<StandardRods> getDefaultRodMatAndColor(String series, String style, String material, String color)
{
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName(schema_name).withCatalogName(procedure_catalog).withFunctionName(procedure_name)
            .declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("lref", OracleTypes.CURSOR,
                            new StandardRodsMapper()),
                    new SqlParameter("p_series_ind", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("p_style_ind", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("p_material_ind", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("p_color_ind", Types.VARCHAR));
    simpleJdbcCall.compile();

    Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();
    inParams.put("p_series_ind", Types.VARCHAR);
    inParams.put("p_style_ind", Types.VARCHAR);
    inParams.put("p_material_ind", Types.VARCHAR);
    inParams.put("p_color_ind", Types.VARCHAR);
    Map output = simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);
    return (List) output.get("lref"); }
```

Mapper function:

```
public class StandardRodsMapper implements RowMapper<StandardRods> {
public StandardRods mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
{
    StandardRods standardRods = new StandardRods();
    standardRods.setSeries(rs.getString("SERIES_IND"));
    standardRods.setStyle(rs.getString("BELT_STYLE_IND"));
    standardRods.setMaterial(rs.getString("MATERIAL_IND"));
    standardRods.setColor(rs.getString("COLOR_IND"));
    return standardRods;
}}
```

Interface:

```
public interface StandardRodsDAO {

List<StandardRods> getDefaultRodMatAndColor(String series, String style, String material, String color);}
```

Junit Test:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringDemoTestingApplication
 {
     StandardRodsDAOImplementation standardRodsDAOImplementation;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "spring-call-proc-simplejdbccall.xml");
    standardRodsDAOImplementation = (StandardRodsDAOImplementation) applicationContext.getBean("standardRodsDao");
}

@Test
public void testGetStandardRod()
{
    List<StandardRods> standardRods = standardRodsDAOImplementation.getDefaultRodMatAndColor("550", "TIGHT TRANSFER FLAT TOP", "NYLON", "DARK BROWN");
    System.out.println(standardRods);
}
```

Procedure:

```
FUNCTION get_std_rods (p_series_ind IN varchar2, p_style_ind IN varchar2, p_material_ind IN varchar2, p_color_ind IN varchar2)
return SYS_REFCURSOR IS lref SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN lref FOR
    SELECT bbv.default_rod_mat, bbv.default_rod_color
    FROM xxlt.xxlt_bpg_belt_val bbv
    WHERE bbv.series_ind = p_series_ind AND
          bbv.belt_style_ind = p_style_ind AND
          bbv.material_ind = p_material_ind AND
          bbv.color_ind = p_color_ind;
  RETURN lref;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems weird for to return an cursor from BDD to Java level. I recommend you to return some value(s) you'll use into the Java, not active element like cursor.

Comment: The issue is resolved. The row mapper was referring to my input parameters and not the output parameters.